# ionic 2 Translate Service

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

I want to implement multilingual suppport to my application where the different language resource file will be getting from the remote server. How to achieve this scenario in ionic 2 typescript as the new file will be write inside the documentsdirectory of an iOS/ andoird application?. Please guide me.

I tried to create a dynamic file in the documents directory programatically and for the TranslateLoader I give the path from the cordova plugin. But I'm getting Cordova not found error as Factory method in the TranslateModule.forRoot() called before cordova platforms ready method called.

Comment: Multilingual support has been done by the TranslateService.SetTranslation method which will be used to set the new language resource json object programatically. Through the above method you can achieve multilingual dynamically from the web service too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multilingual support has been done by the TranslateService.SetTranslation method which will be used to set the new language resource json object programatically. Through the above method you can achieve multilingual dynamically from the web service too.
[ng2-translate reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate)

Comment: How were you able to acheive this? I have a scenario where I need to download translation file from s3 bucket and hot reload the translation file. I tried to save it inside `www/assets/i18n/` of applicationDirectory but it is throwing NOT_FOUND_ERROR.